# Receiving nullpointer exception from method of class object

Tags: java, android, class, nullpointerexception, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that I declare in 'main' XML File:

```
    <com.app.DrawView
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Then in my activity's onCreate method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Which all works fine for displaying the custom view. But what I need to do is pass values to the custom view. So, I tried making an instance of the custom view class:

```
DrawView drawView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```

Then, in the DrawView class, I created a method:

```
public void setUserData(boolean data){
      useEraser = data;
}
```

Now, what my problem is I keep getting a NullPointerExeption when trying to access this method for the DrawView object within my activity, like so:

```
boolean value = true;
drawView.setUserData(value);
```

The error points to the "drawView.setUserData(value)" line. What am I doing wrong? I know I must have made a simple mistake but its driving me crazy trying to find it. Any help or suggestions would be great!

**EDIT:** I accepted an answer which worked correctly, however, I still wanted to know why my original solution did not work. So, I found that, despite the fact that I ordered it correctly in the question, I placed

```
DrawView drawView = (DrawView)findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```

before

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

I knew it was a simple mistake I was overlooking! Thanks for the answers everyone I appreciate it. And I hope this proves to be useful for anyone faced with a similar problem.

Comment: looks to me like drawView is null. Have you debugged the findViewById?

Comment: Perhaps you accidently imported the wrong R so you got the android.R instead of your.package.R?

Comment: drawView is returning null so that must be the reason why I'm receiving the nullpointer exception. Just I'm not too sure why it's returning null

Comment: And it seems as though the R is referencing my package id, example: com.app.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to create new one try this,

put an linearlayout in your xml as a holder

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="300dp" >

    </LinearLayout>
```

and in oncreate use below

```
LinearLayout ln = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ln1);
         com.example.mixed.DrawView dw2 = new DrawView(getApplicationContext());
         dw2.setUserData(false);
         ln.addView(dw2);
```

it works there are no problem if you put it in your layout xml.

[image]

Comment: In my class DrawView I have put both constructors: public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs), public DrawView(Context context). Should I only use one? Would using two make a difference?

Comment: i dont think so. Can you see your custom view on layout editor ?

Comment: My view does show up its only returning null when I'm trying to make an instance of the class for some reason. I put all the code in the DrawView class up

Comment: It works for me ONLY when I use it in xml, like: <com.app.DrawView/>. But when leaving it and xml and trying to get an instance of it in the activity like: DrawView drawView = (DrawView)findViewById(R.id.my_view); the drawView object is null. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: i see now, you can catch with findViewById only if you put it in xml. use this com.example.mixed.DrawView dw2 = new DrawView(getApplicationContext());
         dw2.setUserData(false);

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did solve my problem. Though, I am still confused why my original way of approaching it didn't work, since I had placed the id within the XML.

Answer (score -2):

You do not "receive" exceptions from method calls.  A method might throw an exception which you might catch in a try-catch block.  In that case, the exception would be caught by the catch block.  Otherwise, it would occur inside the method.  Since the caller is throwing the exception, the error is not in your method.

In this case:

```
boolean value = true;
drawView.setUserData(value);
```

The only thing which can be null is drawView.  Therefore, findViewById is returning null or, you are setting drawView to null somewhere else.  You can prove this by putting a breakpoint here:

```
DrawView drawView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```

and inspecting the value of drawView.

From the information you have given, I can't see why it would be but this is the check you must do.

Incidentally, you should always provide all 3 of the view constructors prototypes in a custom view.  You are missing:

```
 public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle){
 super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
```

This constructor is used if the default widget style is overridden.

Comment: Yes, I know how exceptions work and should have been more careful to how I worded my question. But the good news is you still understood what I meant. I appreciate the advice!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm really curious about this one then since you clearly know what you're doing.  If you do find the problem, please do come back with the solution. Ah, I just saw your accepted answer.  Just to be clear, was it the case that you had not placed your custom view inside a view group?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not too sure why my original code didn't work. I had placed my custom view within a view group (Relative Layout) via XML. But when creating an instance of the DrawView class object using 'findViewById', the object would be null. But when I instantiated the object using new DrawView(getApplicationContext()) (as per talhakosen's solution), the object would be instantiated correctly.

Comment: Found the answer to why my original solution did not work, check my edit if interested.

Comment: @AndroidStudent glad t's fixed for you and thank you for coming back to update with the solution.

Comment: Hmm, downvotes with no explanation.  Pretty useless to everyone!